# Unable to make Get request to WCF Service methods

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, iis-8, orchardcms-1.7

I have hosted web services(WCF) on IIS(8.5) in a website(Https Port 443) with a valid SSL Certificate.

I am able to see all service methods when I Browse to the Application over http and can call the service methods to return Json data. then I try to call them over https and service will list all the methods but will refuse to run the methods and will throw error.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.


Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/50848483
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There was no channel actively listening at 'https://MyURL?tea…d=9289&callback=jQuery1111010458340654899811_1461657725831&_=1461657725832'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'https://hypervtest.first-sports.com/RFU/FSI-Services-Host/Competitions.svc/json/GetSeasons?tea…d=9289&callback=jQuery1111010458340654899811_1461657725831&_=1461657725832'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 11016
```

these server methods are already running at a different server.
I have tried with copying the Config and setting the Bindings and same as other server but no luck.

Any Suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this  :[WebInvoke(Method="GET")]

Comment: this is already working on another environment without this attribute.
I think this is due to configuration somehow..